# What is the average distance run by a professional footballer?

Tags: football, english-premier-league

I'm interested to know the average distance a professional footballer covers in a Premier League game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will change dramatically based on the tactic employed by the manager, and the position a player plays in but typically midfielders run the most and cover about 10-11 km over 90 mins. Beyond 11 km is not unheard of but is considered to be a "hard-worker", especially 12+ km. Those players would typically be central midfielders with defensive focus, alternatively defensive midfielders.

References:

- [an article from Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2558428/Premier-League-Stamina-speed-stats-midweek-fixtures.html), not a comprehensive list but representative nevertheless
- Here's [a scholarly article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17024626) on performance stats, mostly based on La Liga and Champions League.